# Cannot convert res.Data (type []twitterstream.rulesResponseValue) to type []byte

Tags: go

I've been wasting many hours trying to pass data from this function to another, and I really need help at this point.

```golang
type Rules struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Tag   string `json:"tag"`
    Id    string `json:"id"`
}

func getRules() {
    accessKey := os.Getenv("API_KEY")
    accessSecret := os.Getenv("API_SECRET_KEY")

    tok, err := twitterstream.NewTokenGenerator().SetApiKeyAndSecret(accessKey, accessSecret).RequestBearerToken()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    api := twitterstream.NewTwitterStream(tok.AccessToken)
    res, err := api.Rules.GetRules()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if res.Errors != nil && len(res.Errors) > 0 {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Received an error from twiiter: %v", res.Errors))
    }


    bytes := []byte(res.Data)
    // this is the line, here 


    var rules []Rules
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &rules)

    for l := range rules {
        fmt.Printf("Id = %v, Value = %v", rules[l].Id, rules[l].Value)
        fmt.Println()
    }

    fmt.Println(res.Data)
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
`cannot convert res.Data (type []twitterstream.rulesResponseValue) to type []byte`

Can somebody help me handle this data? I'm trying to convert the data into my own struct that I can return but it's been one thing after another!

Comment: This may help: https://tour.golang.org/basics/6

Comment: @yangszwei ```cannot refer to unexported name twitterstream.rulesResponseValue```

Comment: You can return the data as `interface{}`, or maybe you can convert the data into your own struct.

Comment: @gfylol you cannot refer to *unexported* identifiers from imported packages. Go simply does NOT allow that. Since `rulesResponseValue` starts with lower case letter it is therefore *unxported*. Only identifiers that start with uppercase letters are exported in Go, and can therefore be referenced outside of the package in which they are declared.

Comment: @gfylol what package is `twitterstream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `Rules` type has the same *underlying type* as the [`rulesResponseValue`](https://github.com/Fallenstedt/twitter-stream/blob/c11c3e7fb375eace4ac757106a2ab8d11208d90d/rules.go#L25-L29) type, you can use the [conversion expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) on the individual elements of the [`Data`](https://github.com/Fallenstedt/twitter-stream/blob/c11c3e7fb375eace4ac757106a2ab8d11208d90d/rules.go#L20) slice to directly convert an instance of type `rulesResponseValue` to an instance of the `Rules` type.

```golang
// I renamed Rules to Rule
type Rule struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Tag   string `json:"tag"`
    Id    string `json:"id"`
}

func getRules() ([]Rule, error) {
    accessKey := os.Getenv("API_KEY")
    accessSecret := os.Getenv("API_SECRET_KEY")

    tok, err := twitterstream.NewTokenGenerator().SetApiKeyAndSecret(accessKey, accessSecret).RequestBearerToken()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    api := twitterstream.NewTwitterStream(tok.AccessToken)
    res, err := api.Rules.GetRules()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else if res.Errors != nil && len(res.Errors) > 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Received an error from twitter: %v", res.Errors)
    }

    rules := make([]Rule, len(res.Data))
    for i := range res.Data {
        rules[i] = Rule(res.Data[i]) // convert rulesResponseValue to Rule
    }

    return rules, nil
}
```

And you can then use that like this

```golang
func main() {
    rules, err := getRules()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, r := range rules {
        fmt.Printf("Id = %v, Value = %v\n", r.Id, r.Value)
    } 
}
```